# Extracting Lanes using osmnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

Im doing a project where I require to create links where:

1. For main Road: a link is the path between adjacent intersections
2. For Lanes: each link is a path consisting of the each lane without taking intersections into consideration.

[Image showing main roads and lanes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quBAZ.png).
 In the image, the yellow box represents main roads and black box represents lanes.
I have found out intersections for main roads using custom filter of osmnx as shown below:

```
cf = '["highway"!~"motorway|motorway_link|primary|trunk|trunk_link"]'
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Sydney,New South Wales,Australia', 
network_type='drive',custom_filter=cf)
Gc = ox.consolidate_intersections(ox.project_graph(G))
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(Gc, edges=False)
intersection_coordinates=nodes[['x', 'y', 'lat', 'lon']]
```

Now similary I would also like to find this for lanes, I tried this custom filter:

```
cf = '["highway"!~"motorway|motorway_link|primary|trunk|trunk_link"]'
```

But it ended up taking my entire RAM. I have seen custom filters for freeways, residentials, cycleways, but haven't had much help for lanes. Since I'm a newbie in osmnx, I would appreciate any help.